# Changing ui-view value programmatically not updating the view itself

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJS and UI-Router and have a list of links which I want to change the view below based on which one is clicked.

Right now on click the value itself changes perfectly, but the view does not change on click.

Here is the state definition

```
.state('home.person', {
            cache: false,
            url: '/person',
            params: {
                personIndex: null,
                personID: null
            },
            views: {
                'mainContent@home.person': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/person/person.html',
                    controller: 'personController'
                },
                'interviewForm@home.person': {
                    template: "interviewform!"
                },
                'employmentDetails@home.person': {
                    template: "employmentDetails!"
                },
                'skills@home.person': {
                    template: "skills!"
                }
            }
        })
```

The HTML

```
<div class="sub-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" ng-click="setSubTab('interviewForm')">Interview Form</a></li>
        <li><a href="" ng-click="setSubTab('employmentDetails')">Employment Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="" ng-click="setSubTab('skills')">Skills</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<pre>{{currentSubTab()}}@home.person</pre>

<div ui-view="{{currentSubTab()}}@home.person"></div>
```

I put the pre in there just so I can monitor the values change easily

And the controller to set/get the current subtab

```
var _currentSubTab = "interviewForm";  // Default
$scope.setSubTab = function (val) {
        _currentSubTab = val;
    };
    $scope.currentSubTab = function () {
        return _currentSubTab;
    };
```

It correctly defaults to and shows interviewForm. If I click Employment Details link the value indeed changes but the view itself does not update! If I change the default value to employmentDetails then it does correctly show that view, but again clicking does not change.

- I've tried adding cache: false but that didn't fix it
- I've tried wrapping the return in a $scope.$apply but I get digest errors
- I've tried using getter/setter functions as you see here, or just using a straight up $scope value and setting it directly in the ng-click but that also didn't work

  1) How can I programmatically update a child ui-view?

**Update**

As Jase suggested below, I know that I can do this by breaking all of these out into their own states. I want to accomplish this feature instead without changing states to update the subtab view.

Comment: Hey, I removed my post from earlier. I just saw in the docs for ui-router for swapping out views like you have above. I'm looking into something else but if I find anything that could help I'll let you know.

Comment: hah thanks a bunch @Jase I know it's possible! :)